# 3D Object Recognition Mixed Reality Audio, Video & 3D Objects

Tags: android, android-augmented-reality, wikitude-sdk

I'm working on augmented-reality. I want to load a 3d model from local asset and play real time audio based on a vertex. check this
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zZ_iRinEnDE
I trying wikitube SDK. how to achieve this in Android Native.